# result set metadata giving me the same column type for both NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, metadata

I try to get the column types using the metadata.
I have columns of type VARCHAR2, NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale) which stores text, integer and float values respectively.
when I use the below code, I'm getting the column type as NUMBER for both NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale).

```
Statement stmt = dbCon.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from TBL_DATA_INFO where 1 = 2");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int noOfcols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for(int i=1;i<=noOfcols;i++) {              
            String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i); 
            String colType = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
            int size = rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(i);
            System.out.println("##Column name: [" + name + "]; type: [" + type + "]; size: [" + size + "]");
        }
```

How should I find whether the column is of NUMBER or NUMBER(Precision,Scale) type.

Comment: `getColumnDisplaySize()` is what the name suggests: it returns the _display_ size of that column. It's neither the precision nor the scale. If you want those, use `getScale()` and `getPrecision()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wager that most readers of this question won't know this.  You should either answer or mark duplicate (assuming you can find a suitable one).

Answer (score 0):

> I have columns of type VARCHAR2, NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale) which stores text, integer and float values respectively. I'm getting the column type as NUMBER for both NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale).

However it is declared, an Oracle NUMBER is not a float: it is quite fixed. Oracle does offer BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE for storing larger values than NUMBER supports. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608)

The difference between NUMBER and NUMBER(Precision,Scale) is that the former allows **any numeric value** which can fit in the datatype but the latter enforces a particular format. Actually, to enforce a rule that a value must be an integer we need to define a scale, that is, NUMBER(*,0) for an integer of any length or NUMBER(4,0) for a four-digit integer.